# Trimmed mean: Take $n$ i.i.d. Gaussians and remove largest $m$ and smallest $m$ points. What is the variance of the mean of the remaining points?

Tags: variance, order-statistics

> Let $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $0 \le 2m < n$. Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be i.i.d. standard Gaussians and let $X_{(1)} \le X_{(2)} \le \cdots \le X_{(n)}$ denote their order statistics (i.e., $\{X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n\} = \{X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, \cdots, X_{(n)}\}$). Define $$Y=\frac{X_{(m+1)} + X_{(m+2)} + \cdots + X_{(n-m)}}{n-2m}.$$
> Clearly, by symmetry, $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$. What can we say about $\mathsf{Var}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$?

A closed-form expression for $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ for all $n$ and $m$ is too much to ask for. Ideally, I want explicit and reasonably tight upper (and lower) bounds. I have the following conjecture I would like to prove.

> **Conjecture.** $$\mathbb{E}[Y^2] \le \frac{1}{n-2m}$$

This is obviously true for $m=0$ and also holds for [$m=(n-1)/2$](http://w3.math.sinica.edu.tw/bulletin/bulletin_old/d102/10211.pdf). The intuition for this is that $Y$ is essentially the average of $n-2m$ standard Gaussians, except the distribution has had its tail amputated, which should only reduce variance.

More generally, I am looking for a bound of the form $$\exists a,b,c\in(0,\infty) ~~~~\forall n \ge b \cdot m \ge a ~~~~~~~~ \mathbb{E}[Y^2] \le \frac{1}{n}\left( 1 + c \cdot \frac{m}{n}\right)~~~~~~~~~~.$$ I want the constants $a,b,c$ to be explicit and as small as possible.

I'm interested in the asymptotics as $n,m \to \infty$ and $\frac{m}{n} \to 0$. For example, $m=\log n$ is a  parameter regime that interests me.

The asymptotic answer as $n\to\infty$ while $m/n \to \alpha>0$ [has been studied](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176342412).

Below are some numerical results (based on the average of $10^6$ draws). The trimmed mean smoothly interpolates between the mean (variance $1/n$) and the median (asymptotic variance $\pi/2n \approx 1.57/n$). Clearly one could hope for better than the conjecture.

[image: variance of trimmed mean as a function of trimming fraction]

The interpretation of this question is as follows. I have $n$ samples from a normal distribution and I discard the largest $m$ samples and the smallest $m$ samples as "outliers". I estimate the mean of the distribution using the remaining samples. This is apparently known as the [truncated mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean) or [trimmed mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmed_estimator).

The question is what is the mean squared error of this estimator? That is, how much does discarding supposed outliers hurt?  (Without loss of generality, for the analysis, I can assume zero mean and unit variance, even though these values would be unknown in practice.)

Ideally I want a result that holds for all "nice" distributions. Nice could mean something like symmetric, continuous, light-tailed, and unimodal. However, any definition of nice should include the Gaussian.

Comment: Does it have to be a Gaussian? For uniform or exponential distributions, an answer could probably be extracted from the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Probability_distributions_of_order_statistics

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Ideally I want a result that holds for all "nice" distributions, but, however "nice" is defined, it should include Gaussian. (E.g., "nice" could be symmetric distributions satisfying some moment bounds.)

Comment: In ["The Asymptotic Distribution of the Trimmed Mean"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176342412) you find an asymptotic result in ["On the variance of the trimmed mean"](https://www.mat.ulaval.ca/fileadmin/mat/documents/lrivest/Publications/34-CaperaaRivest1995.pdf) you find explicit formulas in terms of second moments of order statistics.

Comment: @gg Thanks for the references. "Trimmed mean" is a helpful keyword! The first reference is useful in that gives an approximation when $n\to\infty$ and the ratio $m/n$ is fixed. The problem with the second reference is that I don't know how to compute the pairwise moments of order statistics.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. According to your definition of statistics does $X(1)+X(2)+X(3)$ mean the summation of least 3 random variables among all of them?